# Apache Solr need to group by date

Tags: apache, solr

In Apache Solr I have financial transactions and I need to groupby date and sumup the sales amount. How to do this?

my date field is of datatype **pdate** in solr and the values are like the below for data and sales

```
"2018-10-01T00:00:00Z", 56.25
"2018-10-01T01:50:00Z", 58.35 
"2018-10-01T05:20:00Z", 65.15
"2018-10-02T00:00:00Z", 56.25
"2018-10-03T01:50:00Z", 58.35 
"2018-10-03T05:20:00Z", 65.15
```

How to get the result as sum of sales group by date

```
"2018-10-01", 179.75 
"2018-10-02",  56.25 
"2018-10-03", 123.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a term facet with a nested aggregation facet](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions).

```
json.facet={
  dates: {
    terms: {
      field: transaction_date,
      facet: {
        "total" : "sum(sales_amount)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have given more clarity on the question

Answer (score 0):

Try

> group.query

http://xx.yy.xx.zz:8983/solr/mycorename/select?fl=eventTimeStamp%2Cevent1&group.sort=event1%20desc&group=true&q=*%3A*&group.query=eventTimeStamp:[2019-08-01T00:00:00Z%20TO%202019-08-01T23:59:59Z]&group.query=eventTimeStamp:[2019-08-02T00:00:00Z%20TO%202019-08-02T23:59:59Z]&group.query=eventTimeStamp:[2019-08-03T00:00:00Z%20TO%202019-08-03T23:59:59Z]

Above query can be helpful for you. And use [json-facet-api](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/json-facet-api.html) for sum.

Refer below image.

[image]